# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when building project artifact in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Does anyone know how to fix this error when trying to run command "mvn clean install -U" [ERROR] java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users... -> C:\Users...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have administrator privilege wherever maven is trying to create the build.

Maybe try running your command on a terminal with admin privilege.

Check if your Maven configuration is correct and that you have all necessary configurations and plugins.

Reference: [AccessDeniedException Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html)

Hope this helps.